# What is ${type}Var in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

[This documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html#using-bindings) is very unclear for me when it tries to say what is `${type}Var`.

> ...for Kotlin enums it is named  `${type}Var`

wat?! What is Kotlin enums? Regular Kotlin enums?

```
enum class MyEnum {
    FIRST, SECOND
}
```

I don't think it implied.

Okay, Let's look at the examples in this documentation:

> `struct S*`  is mapped to  `CPointer<S>` ,  `int8_t*`  is mapped to  `CPointer<int_8tVar>`

Okay, it's clear

> `char**`  is mapped to  `CPointer<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>`

Why is `char**` mapped to `CPointer<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>` but not to `CPointer<CPointer<Byte>>`?

So finally the question is: what is `IntVar`, `LongVar`, `CPointerVar<T>` and other things like `${type}Var`?

Comment: You have quoted out of context, the full line is: "For structs (and typedefs to structs) this representation is the main one and has the same name as the struct itself, for Kotlin enums it is named ${type}Var, for CPointer<T> it is CPointerVar<T>, and for most other types it is ${type}Var." yes, it talks about regular kotkin enzyme. No, Byte is not an enum but most other types also follow the ${type}Var pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the whole paragraph again carefully.

> All the supported C types have corresponding representations in Kotlin:
>
> - Enums can be mapped to Kotlin enum

Also in C there are lvalues and rvalues (In C++ the equivivalent is `Type &` for lvalues and `Type` for rvalues). The main distinguish is that lvalues can be set to some value, while rvalues can't be changed after the initialization. So for each type in C you need it's own Kotlin type for lvalue and for rvalue.

In the topic

> All the supported C types have corresponding representations in Kotlin:

only rvalues are considered.
But for lvalues the only thing you need to add is `Var` to end of type. The only exception is

> For structs (and typedefs to structs) this representation is the main one and has the same name as the struct itself

Now let's return to enums. The regular Kotlin enums are mapped to the regular C enums. So actually `FIRST` and `SECOND` have type `MyEnum` in both languages. But what if you want to create a variable containing `MyEnum` for example:

```
// This is C Code
MyEnum a = FIRST;
```

`a` has type `MyEnum` in C, but it's lvalue (in C++ that's `MyEnum &`), so in Kotlin `a` will have type `MyEnumVar` because that's exactly what is said in documentation: `${type}Var`, where `${type} = MyEnum`.

To the next questions:

> The type argument T of CPointer must be one of the "lvalue" types

So for `struct S*` it should be `CPointer<SVar>`, but remember that `struct`s are exceptions and we shouldn't add `Var`, so that's just `CPointer<S>`.

- `int8_t*` is `CPointer<int_8tVar>` - no exception here.
- `char*` is `CPointer<ByteVar>` - again no exception (only lvalue types, except for structs).
- `char**` is `CPointer<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>` as we need lvalue for `CPointer<ByteVar>` and that's exactly `CPointerVar<ByteVar>`.

Finally:
`IntVar`, `LongVar`, `CPointerVar<T>` and other things are lvalues of types `int`, `long`, `CPointer`. That may be needed if you want to change the object in the function. Something like `Ref<${type}>` in Java.

Comment: "The main distinguish is that lvalues can be set to some value, while rvalues can't be changed after the initialization." I wouldn't say so, because `x` in `const int x = 0` is still very much an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> what is `IntVar`, `LongVar`, `CPointerVar<T>` and other things like `${type}Var`?

That's in the beginning of the sentence the end of which you quoted:

> > the Kotlin type representing the lvalue of this type, i.e., the value located in memory rather than a simple immutable self-contained value

"located in memory" means that you can take their address (using `&` operator in C, or [`.ptr`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/ptr.html) in Kotlin).

> wat?! What is Kotlin enums? Regular Kotlin enums?

Yes, so when Kotlin/Native sees `MyEnum`, it also generates `MyEnumVar`.

> Why is `char**` mapped to `CPointer<CPointerVar<ByteVar>>` but not to `CPointer<CPointer<Byte>>`?

`CPointer<CPointer<Byte>>` is illegal: [`CPointer`'s type parameter must extend `CPointed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.cinterop/-c-pointer/index.html#cpointer), and `Byte` and `CPointer<T>` don't. And the reason they need to extend `CPointed` is because dereferencing a pointer gives an lvalue: something that has an address!

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions or https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/ for more about lvalues in C (and C++).